# Rspec test doesn't work well

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

#### What I want to do

I want to examine if an action that includes some processes about changing databases of the controller works successfully.

#### errors

"no save"
  F

Failures:

1) BuysController check #new's behavior return done
     Failure/Error: expect(buy.trading_status).to eq("done")

```
   expected: "done"
        got: "pending"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/buys_controller_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.14739 seconds (files took 3.68 seconds to load)
  1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/buys_controller_spec.rb:6 # BuysController check #new's behavior return done

#### code

```
require 'rails_helper'
include BuysHelper

 RSpec.describe BuysController, type: :controller do
      describe "check #new's behavior" do
       it "return done" do
        User.create(name:"hhhvv",email:"gggjggg@gmail.com")
       p User.find(1)
       Currency.create(name:"hello",user_id:1)
       Sell.create(
           id:1,
          user_id: 1,
         currency_id:1,
          amount:100,
          price:100,
         trading_status:"pending")
       buy = Buy.new(
           id:1,
           user_id: 1,
           currency_id:1,
           amount:100,
           price:100,
          trading_status:"pending"
          )
      if buy.save
          market_checker
       else
          p "no save"
        end
        expect(buy.trading_status).to eq("done")
     end
    end
 end
```

#### What I have tried

```
  rake db:test:prepare 
  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: Use `save!` to see the errors that are raised. It's not advisable to use in the app, but can be really helpful in tests to debug this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'd just been getting an error because of the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to check for errors.

`expect(buy.errors).to be_empty`